# jQuery: how to select element by checking for child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want click  on div  The following conditions but My code does not work properly and returns null value , please help me
I do not understand the concept I want to or not, but most of these do not know how to tell details

JavaScript:

```
$('.helloWorld:contains("helloWorld2"):contains("helloWorld3"):contains("helloWorld4")):contains("max steel")').click();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="helloWorld">
  <div class="helloWorld2">
    <div class="helloWorld3">  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="helloWorld">
  <div class="helloWorld2">
    <div class="helloWorld5">
      <div class="helloWorld3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    
<div class="helloWorld"> <!-- This My Target -->
     max steel
  <div class="helloWorld2">
    <div class="helloWorld3">
      <div class="helloWorld4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to execute something when clicked on a certain div or do you want to execute (simulate) a click on a div? Which div is relevant for you?

Comment: There is a closing `'` missing in your code.

Comment: @gus27 I want to simulate a click I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo-class selector.

```
$('.helloWorld:has(.helloWorld2):has(.helloWorld3):has(.helloWorld4)').click();
```

```js
$('.helloWorld:has(.helloWorld2):has(.helloWorld3):has(.helloWorld4)').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="helloWorld">
  <div class="helloWorld2">
    <div class="helloWorld3">
      a
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781444/how-click-on-div-in-the-jquery/41781513#
<div class="helloWorld">
  <div class="helloWorld2">
    <div class="helloWorld5">
      <div class="helloWorld3">
        b
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="helloWorld">
  max steel
  <div class="helloWorld2">
    <div class="helloWorld3">
      <div class="helloWorld4">
        c
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MaxSteel  : glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) on the divs.

```
$("div[class^='helloWorld']").trigger("click");
```

The selector matches all the divs that has class name that starts with `helloWorld`.
However, i don't see you have a handler defined for the click event.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use something like this:

```
$('.helloWorld .helloWorld2 .helloWorld3 .helloWorld4').click();
```

```js
$('.helloWorld .helloWorld2 .helloWorld3 .helloWorld4').click(function(){
  alert($(this).html());
});
$('.helloWorld .helloWorld2 .helloWorld3 .helloWorld4').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="helloWorld">
    <div class="helloWorld2">
    <div class="helloWorld3">

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="helloWorld">
    <div class="helloWorld2">
    <div class="helloWorld5">
    <div class="helloWorld3">
        
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    //This My Target

    <div class="helloWorld">
    <div class="helloWorld2">
    <div class="helloWorld3">
    <div class="helloWorld4">
            test
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```